# Best Way to Port a SQL Server DB Schema to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What is the best, simplest way to transfer a SQL Server db to MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) comes with the **MySQL Migration Toolkit** which will allow you to easily automate the task of transferring your database to MySQL.

The **MySQL Migration Toolkit** is free.

Not everything is transferable, and for the best results, you are always better of transferring manually.

Comment: I used this tool (albeit with an MS Access legacy DB) and have good experience with it

Comment: This sounds like it should work for me - I only require the database schema (all tables).

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ETL](http://www.smartcode.com/downloads/etl-tool-mysql-server.html) tool.

Comment: DTS? DTS was replaced by SSIS in SQL Server 2005, and was not "excellent" before that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, John.  Apparently I'm basing my opinion on old information.

Answer (score 0):

U can create a script file of your MSSQL db, then run it in MySQL with the help of  MySQL GUI Tools

Comment: How does this cope with different data types between the two DBs, etc ?

Comment: @kevinw: as in all things, you should have to double-check to ensure data types were converted appropriately.