# Anyway to move the schema (and possibly data) from Microsoft SQL Server to MemSQL?

Tags: sql-server, singlestore

I am trying to move my project from MSSQL to MemSQL and running into the initial issue of recreating a ton of tables and associated tables.

Is there a faster tool than extracting manually and fidgeting with data?

I tried SQL Server Import & Export Wizard and tried to export it to MemSQL masquerading as MySQL (since they are binary protocol level compatible), but got a ton of errors even on the simplest of tables.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217487/best-way-to-port-a-sql-server-db-schema-to-mysql -- same idea, but different tools.

Comment: @DavidTansey I've achieved more success with the tool you linked, but it was still a very painstaking process.

Answer (score 1):

Were the errors in the create table statements? 
Unfortunately, MemSQL create table statements have one small caveat beyond MySQL.

I don't know this tool in particular, but the most likely thing such a tool probably gets wrong is forgetting to set a shard key if your table doesn't already have a primary key, or a secondary unique key not containing the shard key.

If you can get reasonable shard keys on your create table statements, moving the data should be easy enough.
The general rules are

1) a table needs either a primary key or a shard key

2) unique keys must contain the shard key.

http://docs.memsql.com/4.1/concepts/distributed_sql/

If you're getting some other error, can you paste it here?

Comment: I reran it...and it seems that the tool recreates schema without keys...so the error is as follows:

`Error 0xc002f210: "CREATE TABLE "Market" (
"EnterpriseMarketId" INT ..." failed with the following error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Market" (
"EnterpriseMarketId" INT NOT NULL,
"Name" CHAR(50) NOT NULL
)' at line 1". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

Comment: I've used the Schema Transfer Wizard in MySQL Workbench with a bit more success.  But it still failed several times with `MySQL server has gone away.   SQL Error: 2006` error while creating schema.  Perhaps that's because the server is in a basic VM in Azure, rather than locally.

Comment: As Joseph said, MemSQL requires you to specify shard keys for distributed tables (unlike MySQL which doesn't have distributed tables). If tables have primary keys, that will work fine, but otherwise you will have to add a shard key yourself. See http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/porting-apps/ for a tutorial.

Your first error is a parsing error because MemSQL does not currently support ""-quotes around identifiers.

Comment: Your second error could mean any number of things. Is the MemSQL server still running and connectable? If not, check the tracelog to see what might have gone wrong.